# MacBook 15 Air won't boot after Catalina install

Tags: startup, catalina

I installed Catalina from Mojave and went through the normal steps. I left it plugged in overnight to download and install, and when I checked it this morning the screen was black with a flashing gray folder icon with a question mark on it.

I googled the issue and tried the various recovery methods (safe mode, boot from another drive, the local and remote system repairs) but none would work. I power cycled each time I tried one of the recovery key combos, but the mac would take a long time to get to the flashing folder icon and would run very hot.

I took it to my local apple store and they told me they would have to send it away for service because "it would not turn on" and they'd have to pull it apart to figure out the issue.

Has anyone else had this problem? The techs made it sound like a hardware issue, but that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Software rarely causes hardware issues. The exception being a Firmware upgrade that goes wrong. Other than that as a possibility any hardware issues during the upgrade to macOS Catalina were likely just coincidental

Comment: Right, so I don't know why the apple store techs would want to look for hardware issues

Comment: Connect your Macbook Air to internet and try the key combination of Shift+Option+Command+R - It installs the macOS that came with your Mac and then see as the last option.

Comment: The Mac doesn’t get to the chime. I have tried all the key combo recovery options and I’m sure the Apple store did as well or they wouldn’t have wanted to send it out for repair. All that happens is the backlight turns on, the Mac heats up, and 25-30s later the gray flashing folder appears.